# GAPI: Failed to request report data. Error: "User does not have any Google Analytics account."

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have problem with gapi. I have many ga_id from sites partners. I need his statistics. My code:`

```
$this->ga = new gapi($myemail, $path_to_key_p12);
        if (false === $this->ga->requestReportData(
            $ga_id,
            array_merge(array('country'), $dimensions), 
            $metrics, 
            '-visits',
            $filter, 
            $datestart, $datefinish,
            1, 1000))
        {
            return false;
        }


    /** @var gapiAccountEntry $result */
    $result = null;
    foreach ($this->ga->getResults() as $result) { 
        $row['site_uid'] = $site_id;
        $row['country'] = $result->getCountry();
        $row['visitors'] = $result->getVisitors(); // unique
        $row['pageviews'] = $result->getPageviews();
        $row['visits'] = $result->getVisits();
        $row['crdate'] = $result->getDate());            
        $this->save_ga_data($type, $row);
    }`
```

it doesn't work. I have:

> GAPI: Failed to request report data. Error: "User does not have any
>   Google Analytics account.
>   but in google developers console this url works.

**UPD**: from google developers console I can get all info 
[image] I use this lib [link](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface) may be I have mistake with her?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably authenticating using Oauth2.   The user  you have authenticated with probably your own Google account.  Does not have access to any Google Analytics accounts.

You need to ask them to grant you access to the account before you are going to be able to request data.

In the event you are using a service account and not Oauth2. You need to give them the service account email address and ask them to add that as a user on the Google Analytics account at the account level it needs only read access.

Comment: oooo, thanks. Do I have any variants resolve this problem without contact owner this accounts?

Comment: Nope you need the account owner to give you permission to access the data.   There is no other way to do it.

Comment: Why I can get info about this sites from developers console, when I don't have acces to accounts?

Comment: You cant get information about this site from google developers console that has nothing to do with Google analytics.   Google analytics data is on https://www.google.com/analytics .    https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0 only contains data about applications accessing Google APIs.

Comment: Can i get informations about visits and pageviews from this place?

Comment: You can only get it from the Google Analytics API, and you need access to the Google Analytics account that you want to get visits and pageviews from.    You cant just read information from my Google Analytics account unless I give you permission to do that.   Its private data.

Comment: Your partners sites have given you the view id already why not just contact them and have them grant you permission.

Comment: this script worked, but google replace authentication with account and password to account and p12 key. I edit this moment, but other doesn't change

Comment: take the service account email address and add it at the admin level of the Google Analytics account. If you are using a service account it needs to be granted access just like any other user. It must be at the account level for it to work.

Comment: thanks, it's solved problem. In last version gapi authorization need gmail email, a nd partners granted access for my account, but in new version authorization need google developer mail, when parthners granted access to my account it's work.